# How do I install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, 19.04

My main goal is to install Tizen Studio IDE so I can learn Tizen development, and I want to do this on Ubuntu.

I have downloaded web-ide_Tizen_Studio_3.2_ubuntu-64.bin and make it executable, and can run this (after a long struggle to install the JDK, but thats another question for another time). But when I do, it says that i have not installed the prerequisites, and I must do the following:

sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 
sudo apt-get install rpm2cpio

The rmp2cpio package seemed to install, but not the libwenkitgtk-1.0-0. It gives me the error:

> ~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate

I have tried searching for a package but it looks like there is not one available (only for older versions of ubuntu) but there must be some way I can force it or even install the version for Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10?

Thank you

Adam

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried this and got:

~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libwebkitgtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libwebkitgtk

Comment: Based on [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0), it seems to only be available for up to 18.10. I would suggest to download the `.deb` file from the PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk), by expanding version 2.4.11-4 of `webkitgtk` for Cosmic (18.10), and downloading `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4.deb` for the correct architecture. Then, use `sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_<your architecture>.deb`. You may also need to install dependencies with `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Thank you very much Eate, I followed those instructions and it worked. There was a dependency for libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb which I installed in the same manner. I was then able to install Tizen Studio. The next problem is that the package manager will not load - just click and nothing happens, and trying to run Tizen Studio (Eclipse?) gives me a very long error message. I will raise another question for this.

Comment: Hm. This might be because it was for another version, and might have broken something — it should still work, though,

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer so that the question can be answered; I'd appreciate it if you marked it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Install 18.04...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0), it seems to only be available for up to 18.10. I would suggest to download the `.deb` file from the PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk), by expanding version 2.4.11-4 of `webkitgtk` for Cosmic (18.10), and downloading `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4.deb` for the correct architecture. Then, use `sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_<your architecture>.deb`. You may also need to install dependencies with `sudo apt install -f`.

Edit: As [@fkraiem](https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem) said, installing 18.04 will also solve your problems, and I personally recommend using the LTS versions unless you *really* want the latest version.

> Install 18.04... – [fkraiem](https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem)

Comment: A note that this was copied from a comment on the question since this solved the issue.

Comment: could you elaborate more on the steps? especially on "expanding" the version. Navigating the PPA page is very alien to me

Comment: Click [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk), scroll or look down until you see a heading in the table of releases, "The Bionic Beaver (supported)". Click on the version you want (currently, `2.4.11-3ubuntu3`) under "The Bionic Beaver", and scroll down to click on "libwebkitgtk-1.0-0: Web content engine library for GTK+". Click on it. Find your architecture (likely amd64) and click on the latest version that says "(Release)" (currently `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 2.4.11-3ubuntu3 in amd64 (Release)` for amd64). Click and download the file under "Downloadable files". Then `dpkg` install.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure this is something stupid to do, but I was running out of options and this solution solved my problem. (please tell me if I did something idiotic).

I created a bionc.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
in than file I added the following line:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
```

I ran an apt update and then installed libwebkit normally...

I needed to run Vega and this was the only way I figured to do it...

Good news - it worked...
I am waiting for the bad news

Comment: This should be an accepted answer...

Comment: This worked for me, too.
But it scared the daylights out of me to sudo unknown commands and have *tons* of stuff loaded as a result.  Can anyone explain *why* this worked to enable Pentaho Pan.sh?

Answer (score -1):

this work now for me

Edit this file to add this

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

At the end add

deb [trusted=yes] http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe

next

sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0