# Tizen Studio not working on 19.04

Tags: eclipse, jdk, 19.04

I have asked a previous question on how to get libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 installed on Ubuntu 19.04 as a prerequisite to getting Tizen Studio installed

[how-do-i-install-libwebkitgtk-1-0-0-on-ubuntu-19-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143637/how-do-i-install-libwebkitgtk-1-0-0-on-ubuntu-19-04)

Now that I have the prerequisites installed, I was able to successfully install web-ide_Tizen_Studio_3.2_ubuntu-64.bin.

The problem I have, is that when I try to open Package Manager, it will give me the spinning loading cursor for a few moments, then nothing happens.

When I try to open Tizen Studio, I get the following error:

[Tizen Studio Eclipse Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdlPT.png)

So I am a bit stuck!

To hopefully assist troubleshooting, these are the commands I used to install everything:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk 

<download libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb and
libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb from
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk under
the Cosmic Cuttlefish / 2.4.11-4 release> 

sudo dpkg -i libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb 

sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb 

sudo apt-get install rpm2cpio
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved the issue, but tried a bunch of things and not 100% on what it was, but:

I uninstalled default-jdk, then installed OpenJDK10 as per:
[openjdk-10-and-openjfx-installation-guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-10-and-openjfx-installation-guide)

That did not fix right away, but then I ran

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java (Select #3, which is "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java")
```

I must have installed OpenJDK 8 at some stage, but don't remember this.

Anyway, it is launching now which is excellent :)

Cheers

Adam